# PHP simplexmlelement fails to find attribute when attribute path is assigned to variable

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My code parses an array to get the paths to various attributes in an xml file.  I load the xml as a simplexmlelement like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$address = $xml->response->addressinformation->records->record[0];
```

This code will work and displays the correct value of '03':

```
$from = $address->{'from-date'}['month'];
echo $from;

//prints '03'
```

The `{}` around `from-date` are necessary because of the `-` in the element name.

The following code blocks seem like they should be functionally equivalent to the above code, but when I assign the path to a $variable it does not work.

```
$path = "{'from-date'}['month']";
$from = $address->$path;
echo $from;

//prints ''
```

```
$path = "from-date['month']";
$from = $address->$path;
echo $from;

//prints ''
```

This code will work.

```
//normal path
$from = $address->{'from-date'};

//path assigned to variable
$path = "from-date";
$from2 = $address->$path;

var_dump($from);
var_dump($from2);

//both correctly output - object(SimpleXMLElement)#1587 (1) 
//{ ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2003" ["month"]=> string(2) "03" } }
```

It only seems to fail when I target the specific attribute with `['month']`. I know the answer to this question is just going to be some silly thing that I'm doing wrong. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Sample XML

```
$xml_string = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <response>
        <addressinformation>
            <records>
                <record id="1">
                    <fullname>JOHN E DOE</fullname>
                    <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
                    <middlename>E</middlename>
                    <lastname>DOE</lastname>
                    <fulldob>01/01/1970</fulldob>
                    <from-date year="2003" month="03"/>
                    <to-date year="2010" month="09"/>
                </record>
                <record id="2">
                    <fullname>JOHN E DOE</fullname>
                    <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
                    <from-date year="2003" month="03"/>
                    <to-date year="2010" month="09"/>
                </record>
            </records>
        </addressinformation>
        <otherinformation>
            <records>
                <record id="3">
                    <fullname>JOHN DOE</fullname>
                    <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
                    <lastname>DOE</lastname>
                    <fulldob>01/01/1970</fulldob>
                </record>
                <record id="4">
                    <fullname>JOHN EDWARD DOE</fullname>
                    <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
                    <middlename>EDWARD</middlename>
                    <lastname>DOE</lastname>
                    <fulldob>19700000</fulldob>
                </record>
                <record id="5">
                    <fullname>JOHN EDWARD DOE</fullname>
                    <firstname>JOHN</firstname>
                    <middlename>EDWARD</middlename>
                    <lastname>DOE</lastname>
                    <fulldob>19830000</fulldob>
                </record>
            </records>
        </otherinformation>
    </response>
</root>
';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible; you can only use a variable for the name of the property you are trying to access, not to then reference that as an array. When you try to use

```php
$path = "{'from-date'}['month']";
$from = $address->$path;
```

you are actually trying to access an object property whose name is `{'from-date'}['month']`, which is why you get no result.

What you could do is specify the attribute using a variable as well:

```php
$path = "from-date";
$attr = 'month';
$from2 = $address->$path[$attr];
echo $from2;
```

which will output

```
03
```

as desired.

Comment: Thanks for this Nick.  Makes perfect sense.  I assumed that the path I was using was just a string simplexml used to locate the note.  I can't do what I'm doing for the same reason that I can't do `$path = 'path->to->some->node'; $node = $address->$path`.  Don't know why I couldn't figure that out on my own last night.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RyanRobinson given the way simplexml works, it wasn't a completely unreasonable assumption. After all, if you had tried that with a regular object, you would have got an undefined property error. Anyway, I'm glad this was useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use something like `"from-date['month']"` as a path to an element, the same way that you couldn't use it in a normal array.  It is expecting it to be 1 level of the array only.

An alternative with XML though is that you could use an XPath expression (you would need to learn XPath, but it may solve a lot of other problems if you are working with XML).

In your case...

```
$path = "./from-date/@month";
$from = $address->xpath($path)[0];
echo $from;
```

gives `03`.

The reason for the `[0]` in the XPath line is that `xpath()` returns an array of matches, so this just picks the first one.

(BTW, you also shouldn't have any whitespace before the `<?xml ...`, so make sure you have something like

```
$xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

)